# ¿ Cómo hacer que sea obligatorio marcar el checkbox del formulario?

Tags: php, javascript, formularios, checkbox

Hola tengo un formulario configurado con PHP y estoy perdido, no se la manera de hacer que sea obligatorio marcar el checkbox que puse en los términos y condiciones.
He puesto el ID pero no se como colocarlo en el archivo PHP. No se si debo añadir algo al archivo javascript.
Les muestro los tres archivos para que puedan decirme como corregir los errores, mas bien que debo añadir al archivo PHP.
Gracias

EDITO LA PREGUNTA
He añadido codigo que me sugirieron,pero el mensaje no se envia, me da error en la consola de google:

```
 POST https://com/includes/contact.php net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

    send @ jquery-1.12.4.js:17
    ajax @ jquery-1.12.4.js:17
    (anonymous) @ form-script.js:21
    dispatch @ jquery-1.12.4.js:16
    r.handle @ jquery-1.12.4.js:16


-- XHR failed loading: POST "https://com/includes/contact.php"

s

    end @ jquery-1.12.4.js:17
    ajax @ jquery-1.12.4.js:17
    (anonymous) @ form-script.js:21
    dispatch @ jquery-1.12.4.js:16
    r.handle @ jquery-1.12.4.js:16
```

//CODIGO PHP AÑADIDO:

```js
// ARCHIVO PHP SUGERIDO POR @Trauma 

<?php

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com:587';             
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';                
$mail->Password = 'password';                         
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
$mail->Port = 587;                                    

$message = "";
$status = "false";

$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    if( $_POST['form_name'] != '' AND $_POST['form_email'] != '' AND $_POST['form_subject'] != '' AND $_POST['form_phone'] != '' AND $_POST['form_message'] != '' ) {

        $name = $_POST['form_name'];
        $email = $_POST['form_email'];
        $subject = $_POST['form_subject'];
        $phone = $_POST['form_phone'];
        $message = $_POST['form_message'];

        $subject = isset($subject) ? $subject : 'New Message | Contact Form';

        $botcheck = $_POST['form_botcheck'];

        $toemail = 'miguelestabaenlaparra@gmail.com';                // Your Email Address
        $toname = 'Unlock Design';                     // Your Name

        if(isset( $_POST['aceptar_terminos'] ) ) {

            $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
            $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
            $mail->AddAddress( $toemail , $toname );
            $mail->Subject = $subject;

            $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
            $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
            $phone = isset($phone) ? "Phone: $phone<br><br>" : '';
            $message = isset($message) ? "Message: $message<br><br>" : '';

            $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

            $body = $name.' '.$email.' '.$phone.' '.$message.' '.$referrer;

            $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
   $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
   'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
   ));
            $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

            if( $sendEmail == true ):
                $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
            else:
                $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
            endif;
        } else {
            $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
        }
    } else {
        $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
    }
} else {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
?>
// ARCHIVO JAVASCRIPT

$(function () {
      $('#contact_form2').validator();
      $('#contact_form2').on('submit', function (e) {
          if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "includes/contact2.php";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                  var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                  var messageText = data.message;

                  var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                  if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                      $('#contact_form2').find('.messages').html(alertBox).fadeIn('slow');
                      $('#contact_form2')[0].reset();
                      setTimeout(function(){ $('.messages').fadeOut('slow') }, 6000);
                  }
                }
            });
            return false;
          }
      })
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<section class="ulockd-contact-page">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="ulockd-contact-form ulockd-style-two">
              <form id="contact_form" name="contact_form" class="contact-form" action="includes/contact.php" method="post"
                novalidate="novalidate">
                <div class="messages"></div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input id="form_name" name="form_name" class="form-control ulockd-form-fg required" placeholder="Nombre"
                        required="required" data-error="Nombre requerido." type="text">
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input id="form_email" name="form_email" class="form-control ulockd-form-fg required email"
                        placeholder="Email" required="required" data-error="Email requerido." type="email">
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input id="form_phone" name="form_phone" class="form-control ulockd-form-fg required" placeholder="Teléfono"
                        required="required" data-error="Numero de telefono requerido." type="text">
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input id="form_subject" name="form_subject" class="form-control ulockd-form-fg required"
                        placeholder="Tema" required="required" data-error="Tema requerido." type="text">
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <textarea id="form_message" name="form_message" class="form-control ulockd-form-tb required" rows="8"
                        placeholder="Su mensaje" required="required" data-error="Mensaje requerido."></textarea>
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="aceptar_terminos" id="aceptar_terminos" value="aceptar_terminos" /> He leído y acepto la <a href="#" target="_blank">Política de Privacidad</a>
                    <div class="form-group ulockd-contact-btn">
                      <input id="form_botcheck" name="form_botcheck" class="form-control" value="" type="hidden">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg ulockd-btn-thm" data-loading-text="Getting Few Sec...">ENVIAR</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: podrias usar el atributo required:  <input type="checkbox" required>

Comment: pero si deseas mayor validacion es con javascript

Comment: ¡¡ **Jamás** se ha de dejar la validación en el lado del cliente !!

Comment: Mi consejo es que valides en los dos lados, en el cliente y en el servidor.

Comment: @alanfcm Bien dicho. Mi comentario debió incluir la palabra `solo` :-(

Comment: Combinando las dos respuestas que te dieron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coincido con lo que han comentado algunos, la validación hay que hacerla tanto del lado del cliente como del lado del servidor.

#### Del lado del cliente

Del lado del cliente yo prefiero un estilo en el que no se permitan al usuario acciones innecesarias para luego mostrarle un mensaje de que se ha equivocado. En este caso es muy sencillo:

1. De entrada colocamos el botón `Enviar` desactivado
2. Lo activamos solamente cuando el formulario **realmente** se pueda enviar. Si la condición para ello es que la casilla de aceptación de términos esté marcada ponemos un *listener*  a ese checkbox, cambiando el estado del botón a activado solamente cuando el usuario haya marcado la casilla. Si la desmarca el botón de desactiva de nuevo. Así, no podrá enviar el formulario si esa condición no se cumple para tenerle que decir luego con un mensaje que marque la casilla.

Si hubiera más condiciones se pondrían todas en esta función, cambiando el estado del botón únicamente cuando todas se cumplan.

```js
document.getElementById("aceptar_terminos").addEventListener('change', checkAccepted);

function checkAccepted(event) {
  var btnEnviar = document.getElementById("btnEnviar");
  console.log(this.checked);
  btnEnviar.disabled = !this.checked;

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="aceptar_terminos" id="aceptar_terminos" value="aceptar_terminos" /> He leído y acepto la <a href="#" target="_blank">Política de Privacidad</a>
<br />
<button id="btnEnviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg ulockd-btn-thm" data-loading-text="Getting Few Sec..." disabled>ENVIAR</button>
```

---

#### Del lado del servidor

El estilo que suelo usar es, guardar los datos pasados por POST en variables, mediante el uso de operadores ternarios. Luego, dejo pasar el código únicamente cuando los datos **esenciales** no vengan vacíos.

Por ejemplo, si lo único que se requiere es que esa casilla esté marcada:

```
$terms=      ( !empty ($_POST["aceptar_terminos"]) ) ? TRUE                : FALSE;
$name =      ( !empty ($_POST["name"]) )             ? $_POST["name"]      : FALSE;
$last_name = ( !empty ($_POST["last_name"]) )        ? $_POST["last_name"] : FALSE;
```

Ahora evaluamos el dato **esencial**:

```
if ($terms) {
    //... se cumple lo esperado trabajamos con los datos usando $name, $last_name
} else {
    //... no se cumple lo esperado
}
```

Si el dato **esencial** fuera la aceptación de términos y el nombre, la evaluación sería:

```
if ( $terms && $name ){
    // ... se cumple
}else{
    // ... no se cumple
}
```

en caso de quere validar y agregar un **filtro** a todos los valores:

> para evitar injeccion de codigo

```
require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
// valida que venga minimo 1 dato, si no termina la ejecucion
//evita asignar varibles o instacias si los datos no son enviados evita carga imnecesaria!
    empty($_POST) ? die("debes completar todos los campos!") : "";
    $datos = array();
    
    // se recorre todo el arreglo post
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // si esta vacia esa posicion salta a la siguiente
        if(empty($_POST[$key])) continue;
        // creamos una varible temporal
        $temp = $_POST[$key];
        // validamos que sea un entero
        if(is_int($temp))
            // filtramos los valores enteros
            $temp = filter_var($temp, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        //validamso que sea un string
        if(is_string($temp))
            // filtramos valores de tipo string
            $temp = filter_var($temp, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        // agregamos la clave a nuestro valor
        $datos[$key] = $temp;
    }
    
    // imprimimos los datos filtrados y listos para trabajar
    print_r($datos);
```

Comment: operador not null ayuda tambien en este tipo de validaciones tan extensas `$terms= $_POST["aceptar_terminos"] ?? TRUE ?? FALSE;`

Comment: @MiguelEspeso la parte de PHP es para el archivo PHP que está en el `action` del formulario, o sea, el que recibe los datos que son posteados desde el formulario. Aunque hayas validado del lado del cliente (Javascript) conviene que también del lado del servidor controles y valides lo que se está recibiendo.

Comment: @Bryro pero me parece que tiene una limitación en el sentido de que no funciona en versiones anteriores a PHP 7 si mal no recuerdo.

Comment: a si cierto toda la razon @A.Cedano creo que solo es php7 tanto tiempo trabajando con la version 7 que ya es como costumbre!

Comment: @Bryro no recuerdo si tú u otro usuario me habló de ese operador en otra respuesta, pero yo no lo uso precisamente por eso, todavía en muchos sitios y páginas web no han dado el salto a PHP 7 por defecto. Mi propio hosting es un ejemplo, es de los más conocidos en el mercado y trae PHP 5 por defecto. Incluso he querido cambiar en cPanel a PHP 7 y he tenido muchos problemas con la web por lo que volví a PHP 5. Había fallos también a nivel de WordPress etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano no me e puesto a ver la compatibilidad pero si puedo imaginarlo aun al dia de hoy sigo trabajando con `python 2.7` aunque la version estable es la 3 pero la migracion es demaciado trabajo

Comment: @MiguelEspeso según la forma en que veo tienes organizadas las cosas, el código de Javascript tienes que ponerlo dentro de este bloque `$(function () { ` y el código PHP tienes que ponerlo al inicio del archivo `includes/contact2.php` que es el archivo que recibe la petición Ajax.

Comment: ¿ Esto también debo añadirlo @A.Cedano ? ` $terms=      ( !empty ($_POST["aceptar_terminos"]) ) ? TRUE                : FALSE;
$name =      ( !empty ($_POST["name"]) )             ? $_POST["name"]      : FALSE;
$last_name = ( !empty ($_POST["last_name"]) )        ? $_POST["last_name"] : FALSE;`

Comment: @MiguelEspeso eso sería en el servidor, en el archivo que maneja la petición Ajax, que es `contact2.php`. Lo que se hace ahí es controlar lo que se mandó desde el cliente al servidor a través del formulario. Se verifica si se aceptaron los términos, y si los input no están vacíos. Ojo, esto `$_POST["name"]` y esto `$_POST["last_name"]` son ejemplos, debes cambiarlo por los valores reales que haya en tu formulario. Creo que deberías investigar un poco sobre cómo funciona Ajax, sobre el envío de formularios, etc. Todas las dudas que planteas se salen ya del problema concreto que planteabas.

Comment: Bueno pues si no saber como aplicar lo que usted me plantea es salirme de lo que pregunte, Gracias @A.Cedano, ya investigare y buscare solución en otro lugar, solo he preguntado como corregir este formulario para que funcione. Por cierto, su solución no funciona. Gracias

Comment: @MiguelEspeso Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas, no podemos en una pregunta y por medio de comentarios dar un curso sobre como funciona Ajax, como se relaciona el código entre el cliente y el servidor, etc. Todo eso da para escribir una biblioteca. He tratado de explicarte brevemente donde tienes que poner cada cosa, pero veo que no lo has entendido. Es imposible explicarlo aquí en comentarios. Todas las respuestas dadas funcionan y hacen lo que requerías en la pregunta. Si tienes otro problema debes primero investigar y si no entiendes preguntas aquí te ayudaremos. Pero esto no es un foro.

Answer (score 2):

Bastar con comprobar, desde PHP, que el `name` del *checkbox* es envíado:

```
if( isset( $_POST['aceptar_terminos'] ) ) {

  // Ok. Checkbox marcado.

} else {
  ...
}
```

Que, aplicado a tu código, quedaría así:

```
...
$toemail = 'example@gmail.com';
$toname = 'Unlock Design';

if( isset( $_POST['aceptar_terminos'] ) ) {
  $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
  ...
```

Si está **sin marcar**, simplemente no se envía.

En [está página de <kbd>www.w3.org</kbd>](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) se indica:

> **checkboxes**
>   
>   Checkboxes (and radio buttons) are on/off switches that may be toggled by the user. A switch is "on" when the control element's checked attribute is set.
>   
>   When a form is submitted, only "on" checkbox controls can become successful. 
>   
>   Several checkboxes in a form may share the same control name.

Lo que, en traducción *muy mucho* libre por mi parte, viene a decir:

> *checkboxes* y *botones radio* son conmutadores *on/off*, a los que el usuario puede cambiar de estado. Están *on* cuando su atributo `checked` está establecido.
>   
>   Cuando el formulario se envía, **solo** los conmutadores en estado *on* serán enviados.
>   
>   Varios *checkbox* en el mismo control pueden compartir el nombre.

Comment: Ya, editado. Solo tienes que colocarlo en tu comprobación, en tu `if( )`.

Comment: Tú tienes esto @Migue `if( $botcheck == '' ) {` borra la variable `$botcheck=='` y agrega `isset( $_POST['aceptar_terminos'] )`

Comment: Pues ya no se decirte ... solo tienes que poner el `isset( )` en el punto en el que quieras comprobar si está o no marcado el *check*. Como lo enfoques, pues ya es cosa tuya :-)

Comment: @VickMuñoz Bien explicado :-)

Comment: @Trauma, ya le di voto útil a tu respuesta! :) Saludos.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso Mas detalles. El código PHP para comprobar el *checkbox* es un simple `isset( )`; es prácticamente *inócuo*. El error tiene que estar en como has organizado tu código.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso Estoy en el curro ahora, no tengo un PHP a mano ... ¿ Que error te da ? ¿ En que línea ? No te hagas de rogar ... :-)

Comment: @MiguelEspeso ¿ Solo eso ? Abre las DevTools y examina la petición, a ver que está pasando ahí.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar una function en `JS` que va desde si esta o no seleccionado el `check`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").required;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="test" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Qué sucede si elimino con DevTools el término `required`?

Comment: No entiendo cual es el proposito de la funcion.